# Sonar Eclipse Plugin - "Test connection"

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I use Sonar 2.4.1,
        Maven 2,
        Eclipse SDK 3.5.
  Sonar is up and running at http://127.0.0.1:9000.

I've installed **Sonar Eclipse Plugin** and when i try to add a sonar server and i click "Test connetion" button (**http://localhost:9000** with or without user and password) i don't get "Connected successfully".

Waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the [Sonar Eclipse Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+IDE/), make sure there is no side effect with the Eclipse proxy setting.
As illustrated in [this bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-136):

> Connection via proxy works fine - tested in real life, but looks like "Test connection" button doesn't work.

So the connection might work fine, but I don't see that correction in that [latest release notes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+Eclipse#InstallingSonarEclipse-NetworkConfiguration).

The OP [Rayouma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473205/rayouma) reports:

> `Eclipse - > Window-> Preferences-> Network Connections`.
>
> Put **`Active Provider`** to "**`Manual`**".
> For the **schema "HTTP"** make `Edit` and put in **host**: "`127.0.0.1`" and in **port** `9000`.
> Re-test the creation of the server Sonar under Eclipse and that works!

Comment: When i try to connect to "http://nemo.sonarsource.org" it displays "Successfully connected!" so i think that the problem doesn't come from proxy configuration!

Comment: My server is Up and when i login (admin/admin) from the navigator it works.

Comment: It's seems that is a proxy problem.

Comment: In fact you should go to Eclipse - > Window-> Preferences-> Network Connections. Put Active Provider to "Manual" For the schema "HTTP" make Edit and put in host: "127.0.0.1" and in port 9000. Re-test the creation of the server Sonar under Eclipse and that works!

Comment: @Rayouma: excellent, I have edited the answer to include your solution.