# Eclipse Plugin Sonar Unable to connect

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I can not set up the sonar qube plguin in eclipse. i have installed it via the eclipse marketplace. 
After this, in the eclipse settings there are config options for the server, default is

`http://localhost:9000`

but if i click "Test Connection" then i get an error "Unable to connect."

after this i change the address to the ip address like this:

`http://192.169.172.30:9000`

but i get the same error. so i search on so and try some of the suggestion, i change the network settings in eclipse like in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596181/1809221

but this doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

My Settings:
OS: Mac OSX
Eclipse: Kepler
Sonar Version: 3.3.0

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Can you connect to the SonarQube web UI at http://192.169.172.30:9000? If that isn't giving you SonarQube, Eclipse won't find it either.

Comment: OK, i have follow what he say under this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7258528/1809221

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been posted in this Question. Please change the network settings for eclipse for SOCKS proxy in manual connection
[How do I have to configure the proxy settings so Eclipse can download new plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin/6459816#6459816)